# Transformar colunas em linhas

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/738aa6/1

```
CREATE TABLE Viagem (
Idasemvolta int,
Idacomvolta int
);

INSERT INTO Viagem 
VALUES (64, 39)
```

Com o seguinte select:

```
select Idasemvolta, Idacomvolta from viagem
```

Essa não é a estrutura completa da tabela, isso foi apenas um exemplo que trouxe de como os números estão aparecendo. No momento, eles estão vindo assim:

```
Idasemvolta     Idacomvolta 
64              39
```

E eu preciso que a estrutura seja essa:

```
Tipo            Valor 
Idasemvolta     64
Idacomvolta     39
```

Já tentei usar o PIVOT, mas não sei o porque no meu banco dá um erro informando que essa função não existe. E o `Group_Concat` tbm não ajuda porque pega tudo e joga em uma única linha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Infelizmente o MySql não tem funções de Pivot table. Nesse caso da pra montar usando um

> UNION ALL

Segue uma possível e bem simples solução:

```
select  'Ida sem Volta' descr, Idasemvolta value
from Viagem
union all
select 'Ida com Volta' descr, Idacomvolta value
from Viagem
```

Como você disse que esse é um pedaço da tabela, caso queira mais itens, para cada coluna que voce deseja que apareça como linha, vai ser necessário ir acrescentando mais *unions* na query

Comment: Minha consulta não ficou perfomática (por conta do meu select inteiro mesmo), demorando 44 segundos para executar. Mas você RESOLVEU o meu problema. Se pudesse daria 5 estrelas. hahha. Valeu. ♥

Comment: Infelizmente não fica rápida mesmo. Mas se resolveu já ajuda rs. Por nada ;)

Answer (score 4):

Realmente, a função PIVOT mesmo não vai ter, mas tem como fazer algo semelhante "na mão". Segue uma exemplo de uma query dinâmica para realizar a tarefa:

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
      ' MAX(IF(Property = ''',
      t.Property,
      ''', Value, NULL)) AS ',
      t.Property
    )
  ) INTO @PivotQuery
FROM
  (SELECT
     Property
   FROM
     ProductOld
   GROUP BY
     Property) t;

SET @PivotQuery = CONCAT('SELECT ProductID,', @PivotQuery, ' FROM ProductOld GROUP BY ProductID');
```

Resultado na variável

```
SELECT
  ProductID,
  MAX(IF(Property = 'Color', Value, NULL)) AS Color,
  MAX(IF(Property = 'Name', Value, NULL)) AS Name,
  MAX(IF(Property = 'ProductNumber', Value, NULL)) AS ProductNumber,
  MAX(IF(Property = 'Size', Value, NULL)) AS Size,
  MAX(IF(Property = 'SizeUnitMeasureCode', Value, NULL)) AS SizeUnitMeasureCode
FROM
  ProductOld
GROUP BY
  ProductID
```

Execução da query

```
PREPARE statement FROM @PivotQuery;
EXECUTE statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
```

Fonte: [pivot-tables-in-mysql](https://codingsight.com/pivot-tables-in-mysql/)